# Make a seamless, continuing texture on two separate models

Tags: texturing, uv

I've made a simple test texture:

[image: Test Picture, it's pretty vital!]

... and a simple test model. Combined, they look like: (in Unity)

[image: Test Picture, it's pretty vital!]

The image above shows two of my test objects. The left-most one is fine to me, but the right isn't. I would like the right one to continue counting where the left one stopped. For example, a brick wall made of two models. I don't want it to get cut off in the middle of the wall, rather I'd like it to continue seamlessly. The real-world application I'm going to use this for is 2D levels of different meshes. I built the levels and the Unity code would randomly place them for me. I'm having a problem here because the textures cut off. I was considering texturing each level individually, but that would be painstaking and it would take up a lot of memory.

Edit:
Please keep in mind that the two objects are different models and different shapes that will be placed in the Unity scene. Most of the methods listed wouldn't work or are not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit and comments, it looks like what you want to do is export the object once, but have it tile seamlessly when a number of copies of the same object are arranged within Unity.

If this is the case, the visible face of the object **must** be textured with an exact whole number of repetitions of the tiling texture (1 or more). Mapping the face to a small section of the texture will not work, as your example image shows.

[image: Object textured with single copy of the tiling texture]

[image: Multiple copies of the object]

Or with a more obviously tileable texture:

[image]

Comment: It worked. But what about if I, for example, want to split the model into three and delete the middle part? If I re-UV map it, then the textures would be off. (My model has two materials - I assign them via Unity). Should I just avoid remapping those faces that should align themselves?

Comment: I'm guessing you dont get alerted on a new comment. Could anybody else try to help me?

Comment: You can subdivide and remove parts of the object without affecting the current UV map. However if you export the left and right parts as separate objects and they are each showing a different portion of the texture, they will not tile seamlessly when placed together.

Comment: I just remembered about this question - thanks for your response. One last question: How would I expand the mesh upwards? I'm using this to create blocks of terrains with bumps, etc. and I tile them in the game. I want to add difference to each terrain block.

Answer (score 9):

Look into UV project modifier.
It allows an object (could be an empty or the camera) to project an image into UV unwrapped objects, Very easy to control the size and positioning in real time.
[image]

Comment: Would that work in Unity?

Answer (score 7):

Since the models are identical and fairly simple, a quick way you could do this is to make them into one object (or just model one object), unwrap that object and map the single texture to it.

Next, split the object with a loop and separate a half by selection. Blender will preserve the position of the uvs on both for you. It would also be fairly easy to have it wrap etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by duplicating the mesh and modifying it's UVs

1. Duplicate the mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
2. Select the second mesh and go into edit mode, <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. In the UV Editor select all UVs and move them along the x-axis (or the y-axis, it depends)

[image]

Comment: Ah, but I'm importing these models into Unity, and both of the objects in the scene are different models. The point is that whichever way it's arranged, the texture still seamlessly continues.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this, depending on a couple different factors.

The way that I would use that should work no matter what, is to simply "join" the two objects into one, you can then UV map the texture appropriately.

Also, if your using cycles (which you should) you can map the texture based on the coordinates of the object in question with a object info node (Add Node > Input > Object Info)

You could also use texture painting. I couldn't give much insight on texture painting... you should google the docs on it, and watch some YouTube videos.